# SQL query conversion to laravel query building

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5.3

I am new in laravel 5 sql query building and I face a challenge of converting sql to laravel 5.x sql query.

Below is the normal sql:

```
select users.name as name, count(ticket.id) as total, sum(ticket.quantity * ticket.amount) as montant 
from users 
inner join program on program.driver_id = users.id
inner join line on line.id = program.line_id
inner join trip on trip.program_id = program.id
inner join ticket  on ticket.trip_id = trip.id
where program.date = $date
group by users.name
```

which give me the response I need.
but the laravel version of my code returns nothing. Below is my code

```
$result = \DB::table('users')
                ->select('users.name as name', \DB::raw('count(ticket.id) as total'),\DB::raw('SUM(ticket.quantity*ticket.amount) as montant'))
                ->Join('program', 'program.driver_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->Join('line', 'line.id', '=', 'program.line_id')
                ->Join('trip', 'trip.program_id', '=', 'program.id')
                ->Join('ticket', 'trip.id', '=', 'ticket.trip_id')
                ->where('program.date', $date)
                ->groupBy('users.name')
                ->get();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your query builder looks fine to me

Comment: thanks for your contribution. Actually it's ok, I noticed my test data has yesterday's date whereas the query is fetching for today's activities

Comment: which is the attribute $date define as a parameter of the function that returns this result

Comment: I guess there was no issue ?

Comment: yes, my bad. I would have looked closer. When you confirmed that it was correct it made me to have a review with closer look

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$result = DB::table('users')
                ->selectRaw('users.name as name, count(ticket.id) as total, SUM(ticket.quantity*ticket.amount) as montant'))
                ->join('program', 'program.driver_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->join('line', 'line.id', '=', 'program.line_id')
                ->join('trip', 'trip.program_id', '=', 'program.id')
                ->join('ticket', 'ticket.trip_id', '=', 'trip.id')
                ->where('program.date', $date)
                ->groupBy('users.name','ASC')
                ->get();
```